# Set the same value in a column based on other column's value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which contains a `id` column and a `name` column. The same name value should always be used for each id value, but that is unfortunately not the case. See example below:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'id': [1, 1, 2, 2], 'name': ['Name1', 'Name 1', 'Name2', 'Name 2'] }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

   id    name
0   1   Name1
1   1  Name 1
2   2   Name2
3   2  Name 2
```

You see that the rows with id value 1 have either 'Name1' or 'Name 1' as name value and the rows with id value 2 have either 'Name2' or 'Name 2' as name value. What code can be used to change the dataframe, such that always the **same** name value is used for a particular id? Example what is wanted:

```
   id   name
0   1  Name1
1   1  Name1
2   2  Name2
3   2  Name2
```

Which value doesn't really matter as long as the same value is used.

Comment: I think `transform('first')` should working well here

Comment: @jezrael thanks. This is the full statement to do the trick `df['name'] = df.groupby('id')['name'].transform('first')`